# Set up automatic payments for my debit card, with my debit card or on debit card?

Tags: prepositions

Could you tell which preposition do I use in the sentence below: *for*, *with* or *on*?

> I'd like to set up automatic payments **for**/**with**/**on** my debit card.

Comment: I'd use "using".

Comment: Which one do you mean? They all mean something different

Comment: [Could you tell me which preposition I should use]

Comment: In my experience, one sets up automatic payments (either direct debits or a standing order) on a current account (to which a debit card may be linked).

Comment: "on" is the most natural preposition to use

Comment: Is it payments from your card or to your card (to put money on a card or pay bills)?

Comment: In the UK, there's a specific name for such payments,  it's called a **direct debit**.  You would say "I want to set up a direct debit".  It may have a different name in other English speaking countries.  Note also this method of paying is not generally linked to a specific card, but rather a bank account.

Answer (score 0):

@RonaldSole is correct, the automatic payment is really a property of your account, not your card.

That being said, if you are going to be setting these up **with/using** your debit card, then say “with”/“using”.